# How to refactoring this code with STL?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Here is my exercise code ..
books question is refactoring this code to template (with STL)

i found some books and google but i don't get it

can you show me example please??

```
int SumInt(const int* a, int count) {
     int result = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
     result += a[i];
     }
     return result;
}

float SumFloat(const float* a, int count) {
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    result += a[i];
    }
    return result;
}
void main() {
    int intVals[] = {0, 1, 2};
    float floatVals[] = {0.F, 1.F, 2.F};

    int intTotal = SumInt(intVals, 3);
    float floatTotal = SumFloat(floatVals, 3);

 .... 
}
```

Comment: Start out with replacing the raw arrays with `std::vector`: `std::vector<int> intVals {0, 1, 2};` `std::vector<float> floatVals = {0.F, 1.F, 2.F};`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: If your book tells you `void main`, it's not a C++ book.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
int intTotal = std::accumulate(std::begin(intVals), std::end(intVals), 0);
float floatTotal = std::accumulate(std::begin(floatVals), std::end(floatVals), 0.0F);
```

Answer (score 3):

Within this example, you can replace both `SumInt` and `SumFloat` with a template `Sum` as follows:

```
template <typename T> int Sum(const T* a, int count) {
     T result = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
         result += a[i];
     }
     return result;
}
```

Then in your `main()`, you can call

```
int intTotal = Sum(intVals, 3);
float floatTotal = Sum(floatVals, 3);
```

and the compiler will call either the `int` or `float` version depending on the type of argument you supply to `Sum`.

Comment: Basically the idea is to replace a specific data type (int this case `int` or `float`) with a generic one. People often use 'T' as a symbol for a generic type.

Answer (score 2):

An implementation involving template parameters and use of STL (c++ standard library):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef> 

template <typename T>
T Sum(const std::vector<T>& a) {
     T result = 0;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
         result += a[i];
     }
     return result;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> intVals {0, 1, 2};
    std::vector<float> floatVals {0.F, 1.F, 2.F};

    int intTotal = Sum(intVals);
    float floatTotal = Sum(floatVals);

    std::cout << intTotal << std::endl;
    std::cout << floatTotal << std::endl;
}
```

See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c60fe471d7ffae)

Comment: Do you really need to specify the `<int>` or the compiler can deduce that the vector `intVals` is composed of `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Here we go (a simple template for your sum(...) function):

```
template <typename T>
T sum(const T* a, size_t count) {
    T result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result += a[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const int intVals[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    const float floatVals[] = { 0.F, 1.F, 2.F };

    const int intTotal = sum(intVals, 3);
    const float floatTotal = sum(floatVals, 3);

    std::cout << "float total: " << intTotal << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int total: " << floatTotal << std::endl;
}
```

I do like [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), though:

```
int main() {
    const auto intVals = { 0, 1, 2 };
    const auto floatVals = { 0.F, 1.F, 2.F };

    const auto intTotal = std::accumulate(intVals.begin(), intVals.end(), 0);
    const auto floatTotal = std::accumulate(floatVals.begin(), floatVals.end(), 0.0F);

    std::cout << "float total: " << intTotal << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int total: " << floatTotal << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use templates like this. Also read on them: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

```
template<typename T>
T doSomething(const T a, int count)
{
  // do your stuff

}
```

You use it like this:

```
int w = 1;
doSomething(w, 1);
```

You are replacing `T` with `int` in this case

Comment: You don't need to specify `<int>` in this case. The compiler can deduce it. Just call `doSomething(1, 1)`